# Shaded area in archimedes spiral. Please validate.

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the shaded area and this is how I am doing it.

$$\frac12\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi} \theta^2 \, d\theta = \frac 1 2 \left[{\frac{\theta^3}3}\right]_{2\pi}^{3\pi}  = \frac12\left(\frac{27\pi^3}{3}-\frac{8\pi^3}{3}\right)$$

$$My\,Calculation\; \frac{19\pi^3}{6} $$

$$Expected\,Answer\;3\pi^3$$

Is the expected answer wrong? or Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Shaded area in spiral of archimedes]

Comment: you need to subtract out the inside of the spiral.  $\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi} \frac 12 \theta^2 \ d\theta - \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac 12 \theta^2 \ d\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That integral gives the area bounded by that section, but totally ignores the area cut away by a previous section of the curve, specifically that on $[0, \pi]$. Computing and subtracting that gives the desired result.